# SQL Joining two tables and removing the duplicates from the two tables but without loosing any duplicates from the tables itslef

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates, union

I want to join two tables and remove duplicates from both the tables but keeping any duplicate value found in the first table.

T1

```
Name
-----
A
A
B
C
```

T2

```
Name
----
A
D
E
```

Expected result

```
A - > FROM T1
A - > FROM T1
B
C
D
E
```

I tried `union` but removes all duplicates of 'A' from both tables.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So if `T2` has two rows with `B`, you'd want `A, A, B, B, C, D, E`, i.e. you want the number of duplicates from the file with the most repetitions for each value?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. That's correct. Don't want to remove the duplicate from the table itself. Thanks

Comment: @Rick707 . . . Your question is a bit incomplete.  It could be interpreted as only the first table has duplicates and I only want one column.  Or it could be interpreted as there are really many columns and I don't want the names duplicates.  Or all columns duplicates.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 4):

Filter `T2` before `UNION ALL`

```
select col 
from T1
union all
select col 
from T2 
where not exists (select 1 from T1 where T1.col = T2.col)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the number of duplicates from the table with the most repetitions for each value, you can do it with the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function, to eliminate duplicates by their sequence with the set of repetitions in each table.

```sql
SELECT Name FROM (
   SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
     FROM T1
   UNION
   SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
     FROM T2
) x
ORDER BY Name
```

---

To see how this works out, we add two `B` rows to `T2` then do this:

```sql
SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
  FROM T1
```

```
Name  Row
A     1
A     2
B     1
C     1
```

---

```sql
SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
  FROM T2
```

```
Name  Row
A     1
B     1
B     2
D     1
E     1
```

---

Now `UNION` them without `ALL` to combine and eliminate duplicates:

```sql
SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
  FROM T1
UNION
SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS Row
  FROM T2
```

```
Name  Row
A     1
A     2
B     1
B     2
C     1
D     1
E     1
```

---

The final query up top is then just eliminating the `Row` column and sorting the result, to ensure ascending order.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8632/7) for demo.

Answer (score 1):

you should use "union all" instead of "union".
"union" remove other duplicated records while "union all" gives all of them.

for you result,because of we filtered intersects from table 2 in "where",we don't need "UNION ALL"

```
select col1 from t1
union
select col1 from t2 where t2.col1 not in(select t1.col1 from t1)
```

Comment: UNION ALL would also return the A from T2.

Comment: yes."union all" return all "A" from T1,T2 . what thing do you want?

Comment: Take a look at the expected results in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from T1
union all 
select * from T2 where name not in (select distinct name from T1)
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91d47/5)

Comment: using `distinct` there is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I D'not know the following code is good practice or not  But it's working

```
select name from T1 

UNION

select name from T2 Where name not in (select name from T1)
```

The Above Query Filter the value based on T1 value and then join two tables values and show the result.

I hope it's helps you thanks.

Note : It's not better way to get result it's affect your performance.

I sure i update the better solution after my research

Answer (score 0):

You want all names from `T1` and all names from `T2` except the names that are in `T1`.
So you can use `UNION ALL` for the 2 cases and the operator [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to filter the rows of `T2`:

```
SELECT Name FROM T1
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT Name FROM T2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT Name FROM T1
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c05efef036727da609987f45b9d7c4c).
Results:

```
> | Name |
> | :--- |
> | A    |
> | A    |
> | B    |
> | C    |
> | D    |
> | E    |
```